# Keep contents docked in their position like Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, web

I am currently building my own website (HTML) and I discovered that if I adjust the size of my browser, all the things inside my website adjusts as well--like if you make the browser really-really small, my website's contents pile up in a single tower-like thing. In short terms, my website only works when your browser is on full-screen(maximized) but when you adjust the browser size, it will disarranged the content unlike facebook--facebook's contents literally just stays in place whether you make it maximized or not..

Please can you help me?

Thanks and peace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any info on how you built the site, all I can say is make use of the css `min-width` tags.

Also try to look at a page, which acts in your preferred way, source.